# I need to learn id of an element using php to update it on database

Tags: php, html, element

I am trying to make an product listing page. So i need to make delete and update buttons for all of them. So, i found an idea that can help me. Its something like that;

```
<form method="post">
<button name="delete" id="product12">delete</button></form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
 #i need to get elements id to delete them from database
}
```